# Is there any way to load the txt file in android app code without writing it in the android device?

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-ndk

**What I do:**

1.I have a simple facedetection code in which I load a xml file(or txt file).

2.For that first I write the xml in the device and then loaded in the application.

3.Sample code I used to write

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.haarcascade_frontalface_alt);
File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
is.close();
os.close();
```

4.From the above code the xml is writtern in the data/data folder in device

**What I need to do:**

1.I need to load the xml in the app in such a way that others cannot able to find which xml is loaded(may be using the jar file)

Is there any way to do so?

**UPDATE:**

I am planning to share my project as SDK,I want to hide the xml which I used from other users

We cannot able to access the xml file from the raw folder because we calling it from the native library.so we are loading it from data/data folder

Comment: Who are _"others"_? What does _"loaded"_ mean exactly?

Comment: Also, it's not entirely clear why you need to write the data to a new file, instead of just reading it from the resource like you're already doing in the code you've shown us.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the reply,i have updated the question.

Comment: _"We cannot able to access the xml file from the raw folder because we calling it from the native library.so we are loading it from data/data folder"_ The functions you call in the above Java code to read the resource can also be called from native code through JNI.

Comment: @Michael Actually reading the file from native is not the issue,My main concern is "I need to load the xml in the app in such a way that others cannot able to find which xml is loaded if i shared the SDK"

Comment: Well, it's still not really clear exactly what you're trying to protect against. If your app is able to do X, then someone with enough privilege will be able to tell that you've done X. All you can do is make this more difficult, not prevent it altogether. Some ideas would be to load _all_ xml files but only used some of the data, an/or encrypt the xml files (requires keeping the key safe somehow), and/or obfuscate your code if you haven't already done so. It all depends on the method by which you expect someone to _"find which xml is loaded"_.

Comment: @Michael I have few  doubts to clarify,can  you please joint the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122405/android-hide-xml